# Pentaho Data in Excel Template

Tags: pentaho-data-integration

I'm not sure how to explain this. I'm new to Pentaho Data Integration,and I need to get data into an excel file in a certain order. Example a specific title goes in A1 and date goes in A2
B1 is where the data list start. The last row have to have specific data in A1 and A2. Is there a way to do this in Pentaho? I tried using Execute SQL script->Microsoft Excel Writer but I'm completely lost.

Comment: Could you send an example of how data is coming in and how data should be... table examples, images should suffice.

Comment: [excel ex.]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u22XY.png The yellow highlighted is what always as to be at the top. The Orange is the data from the database. The blue is what always has to be on the last row. A2 row six is the total count of rows starting at B1

Comment: What you have in Yellow is called a Header, this is almost always be default to save on the excel file. I think you're having your references wrong, A2 row six doesn't exist, what you mean is row 6 of column A, that is an aggregation of informations. I think what you mean is that it is the total count of Headers after B (C + D = 2 columns). Either that or i have no idea what want.

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it, thanks for trying. I may have to look over it again. Basically I just want Pentaho to populate the excel sheet with the information in the image but in the exacts rows and columns. Just trying to figure out if Execute SQL script->Microsoft Excel Writer steps would help?

Comment: Try it with 'Table input' step, then 'Microsoft Excel Writer' step. 'Execute SQL Script' step is used for another purpose.